# Number theory/Polynomials division proof

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, summation, proof-writing

This question was in my last exam and I still don't know how to do it, at all. I'm studying for the resit, so I figure I should at least give it a go, even though it seems to involve number theory which is, by far, my worst topic. The question goes:

Show that: $$\sum{n \choose k}  = \frac{2^n+2 \cos (\frac{n{\pi}}{3})}{3},$$
where the sum is taken over all integers k which satisfy 0 $\leq$ k $\leq$ n and 3|k.

Could somebody walk me through it?
Thank you

Comment: Use the binomial theorem for cube roots of unity.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $\omega$ be a complex $3^{rd}$ root of unity, then $\omega^3 = 1$ and $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$.

If $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots$ then $$f(x)+f(\omega x)+f(\omega^2 x)=3(a_o+a_3x^3+a_6x^6+\cdots)$$